# How to edit json file with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I want to write data in json file using `PHP` like below example but it always adds data outside square brackets(arrays).

How can I write inside the square brackets?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. Modify your code to like below:

```
$current_data = file_get_contents('users.json'); 
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);

$array_data["users"][] = array (          //   -> this line has been changed
         'name'        =>     $_POST["name"],  
         'mobile'      =>     $_POST["mobile"],  
         'datedon'     =>     $_POST["datedon"]  
          );

$final_data  = json_encode($array_data);  
...
```

**Edited:**

If you want to add the item to the begin of your array use [array-unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
...
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
$item = array ( 
         'name'        =>     $_POST["name"],  
         'mobile'      =>     $_POST["mobile"],  
         'datedon'     =>     $_POST["datedon"]  
          );
array_unshift($array_data["users"] , $item);
$final_data  = json_encode($array_data);  
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother. :)

Comment: @GopalMeena - You welcome! If this post helped you - you may mark it as accepted so other may use it (the grey "v" mark at the left of the answer)

Comment: Thanks bro! But this code adds data at the end of json file, how to add new data at the beginning (Start) of the json file like in the question i asked.

Comment: @GopalMeena Edited with adding the data at the begin

Comment: Sorry to say brother but it's not adding any new data in json file.

Comment: Did you remembered the `file_put_contents`? use `var_dump($array_data)` to verify the data exist before save

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Change your code from this:

```
$extra[] = array ( 
         'name'        =>     $_POST["name"],  
         'mobile'      =>     $_POST["mobile"],  
         'datedon'     =>     $_POST["datedon"]  
          );

$array_data[] = $extra;
```

So that it looks something like below:

```
$array_data['users'][] = array (          
         'name'        =>     $_POST["name"],  
         'mobile'      =>     $_POST["mobile"],  
         'datedon'     =>     $_POST["datedon"]  
          );
```

**Solution 2**

Change the line

```
$array_data[] = $extra;
```

to below:

```
$array_data['users'][] = $extra;
```

Comment: Thanks bro! But this code adds data at the end of json file, how to add new data at the beginning (Start) of the json file